# Apache Flink - Error: method apply not applicable for the arguments (WindowFunction)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new using Apache Flink. I read data from a Apache Kafka source and need to transform the `DataStream`.

In the last step I try to apply a `WindowFunction`:

```
DataStream<Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>> dataStream = 
                     env
                    .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<>(
                                    parameterTool.getRequired("topic"),
                                    new SimpleStringSchema(), 
                                    parameterTool.getProperties()))
                    .flatMap(new SplitIntoRecordsString())
                    .flatMap(new SplitIntoTuples())
                    .keyBy(1)
                    .countWindow(5)
                    .apply(new windowApplyFunction());

    public class windowApplyFunction implements WindowFunction<
                                                            Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>, 
                                                            String,  
                                                            Double, 
                                                            Window>{

    public void apply(Double key, Window window,
            Iterable<Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>> values,
            Collector<String> out)
            throws Exception {      
        out.collect("MyResult");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I got the following Error and don't know how to fix it:

```
The method apply(WindowFunction<Tuple8<Double,Double,String,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double>,R,Tuple,GlobalWindow>) in the type WindowedStream<Tuple8<Double,Double,String,Double,Double,Double,Double,Double>,Tuple,GlobalWindow> is not applicable for the arguments (FlinkManager.windowApplyFunction)
```

Everything works fine if I replace the `apply(new windowApplyFunction())` with a predefined function, e.g. `sum(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WindowFunction` should be type of

```java
WindowFunction<
    Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>,
    String,
    Double,
    GlobalWindow>
```

`countWindow()` returns **`GlobalWindow`** type.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your hint vanekjar! After correcting this fault I changed another small thing and it works now! 
The correct code:

```
public static class windowApplyFunction implements WindowFunction<
                                                            Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>, 
                                                            Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>, 
                                                            Tuple, 
                                                            GlobalWindow>{

    public void apply(Tuple key, GlobalWindow window,
            Iterable<Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>> values,
            Collector<Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>> out)
            throws Exception {      
        out.collect(new Tuple8<Double, Double, String, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double>());
    }
}
```